# Could someone explain the 'hit' and 'miss' status in memcache per page output?

Tags: caching

I've instructed memcache to append stats to each page. Someone did an [excellent job explaining the memcache reporting](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/159168/5966) page. However, I've since stumbled upon this appended information shown below and am curious.

Specifically what are miss and hit status?

([enlarge picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7q06.png))
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hit/miss statuses are the result of the cache being touched as the result of the operation. For the given operations:

- **Get:** (for a single key) **Hit:** data was retrieved from the cache; **Miss:** data was found not in the cache.
- **Set:** **Hit:** data was stored in the cache; **Miss:** data was not stored in the cache.
- **GetMulti:** (for multiple keys) **Hit:** data was retrieved in the cache; **Miss:** data was found  not in the cache.
- **Delete:** **Hit:** data was removed from the cache; **Miss:** data was not removed (for a missing key) in the cache.

Comment: So hits > miss is good.

Comment: For gets, yes, you want the hit/miss ratio to be as high as possible.